# Error while connecting to postgresql using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm trying to connect to a postgresql database aiming to retrieve data from some of the tables in the database.

I followed the [node-postgres docs](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting) while writing the code, tried connecting using connection string as well as a config object but ended up with the following error.

```
(node:30315) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: database " /dw" does not exist
at Connection.parseE (/Users/swagnikdutta/Desktop/Rupeek/db-crawler/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:606:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/swagnikdutta/Desktop/Rupeek/db-crawler/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:403:19)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/swagnikdutta/Desktop/Rupeek/db-crawler/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:123:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

Then I used the `pg-promise` library to connect but still got the same error. Here's my code (all approaches included)

```js
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg');
const parse = require('pg-connection-string').parse;
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

const { connectionString } = require('../config/index');
const db = pgp(connectionString);

exports.readData = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const connectionConfig = parse(connectionString);
        const client = new Client(connectionConfig);
        // or
        // const client = new Client({ connectionString });

        client.connect();
        client.query('SELECT NOW()', (err, res) => {
            console.log(err); // logs the error
            client.end();
        });

        /**
         * Using pg-promise as an alternative to above
         */
        let sco;
        db.connect()
            .then(obj => {
                console.log('Check', obj); // does not print
                sco = obj;
                return sco.any('SELECT * FROM payments_loanpayment');
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data); 
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error); // logs the error!
            })
            .finally(() => {
                if(sco) { 
                    sco.done();
                }
            });


        // return res.send('OK');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }    
}
```

I looked up for similar issues but could not find a solution that explains why this happens. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: Added connection string

```
postgresql://<username>:<userpassword>@datawarehouse.gcbewejpbwvm.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com%20/dw?statusColor=323232&enviroment=local&name=dw&tLSMode=0&usePrivateKey=false&safeModeLevel=0&advancedSafeModeLevel=0
```

Comment: Where is your connection string

Comment: it says it cannot find the database specified in the connection string

Comment: Reading the error `error: database " /dw" does not exist` it seems that you have an extra space before /dw. Without seeing the actual connection string we can't really say more.

Comment: `com%20/dw` %20 is an encoded space symbol. Why is it there?

Comment: I have added the connection string in the question. @StephaneM I had noticed the weird space earlier, which is why I converted the string into an object. In the object I removed the space using `connectionConfig.database = connectionConfig.database.slice(1)` but still the error happened.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for pointing out the issue, that fixed it. I should have paid more attention to the connection string.

Comment: You should use either `pg-promise` or `pg`, there is no point including both in your project. Besides, `pg-promise` contains `pg` module.

Comment: @vitaly-t I know, I was just trying out different approaches. (Commented a particular section while testing code in another section). Now that it is resolved, I'm just using pg-promise and removed everything else.